# How to clear the value of a Rich text field in Lotus Notes

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a Rich Text field in Lotus Notes. But I am not sure how to clear the contents of the field.
I have tried the following:

1. `ReplaceItemValue`:

```vb
doc.ReplaceItemValue("RichTextField", "")
```

`ReplaceItemValue` does not work for a Rich Text field.

2. `vRTItem.Values = ""`:

```vb
Set vRTItem = doc.GetFirstItem( "RichTextField" )
vRTItem.Values = ""
```

This didn't help.

3. `RemoveItem`:

```vb
Set vRTItem = doc.GetFirstItem( "RichTextField" )
Call doc.RemoveItem("RichTextField")
Set vRTItem = doc.CreateRichTextItem( "RichTextField" )
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to see the all the code you've written and where this code is triggered (document event, button, agent, etc)

What you have should work but you need to save the document after you call those methods:

```
doc.Save(false, false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The "First" in the doc.GetFirstItem() method is a hint that there may be more than one.

I'd go with the doc.RemoveItem("theNameOfTheItem") : be sure to save the doc afterwards, before doing anything else with the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using the `NotesRichTextRange` class. In this case `doc` is your `NotesDocument` containing the rich text item you want to change. Note: the rich text item is still in the document but it has no content.

```
Dim rti as NotesRichTextItem, rtr as NotesRichTextRange

Set rti = doc.getFirstItem("RichTextField")
Set rtr = rti.Createrange()
Call rtr.Remove()
```

The default range for a new NotesRichTextRange is the beginning and end of the item as per the [documentation](https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/9.0.1/appdev/H_NOTESRICHTEXTRANGE_CLASS.html) so you don't need to set the beginning and end.